# apt-get update only works through a proxy

Tags: apt, iptables

I have a ubuntu server (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS) that hosts KVM VPS, manages through Virtualizor (3.0.2). Inside those vps, I am unable to perform apt-get update. The command works on the main server itself.

> 0% [Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.24)] [Connecting to
>   security.ubuntu.com (91.189.88.174)]

At first I tought it was a problem with the sources, but when I setup a proxy, the command works just fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which release number of Server? Please click [edit] and add that into your question.

Comment: Check the output of `apt-config dump` for Proxy entries.

Comment: Do you have external routing configured in your kvm?

Comment: @user535733, I see no output related to proxy. Also compared both dump (server vs vps) to look for differences.

Comment: @SebastianOliva, do you have recommendations of files/commands I could output to check for that. My KVM are managed with Virtualizor, I will add this to the question.

Comment: Are the VMs configured with static IP addresses or are they setup to use DHCP? It could be that you have the default gateway wrong if they are setup to use static IPs. Also, is this a home lab or are you at work? I only ask because your work network might have firewall settings in place to block the network traffic. Please add this information into your question.